# What 1980's kids book series about boy learning magic spells?

Tags: story-identification

About 1987, I read an adventure/fantasy novel series about a boy who learns magic and his adventures. He would learn new spells with each new book of the series. I'm looking for any additional info or suggestions.

The titles went along this line based on a new spell:

- "I" is for Invisible or Illuminate
- "T" is for Teleport(ation)
- "L" is for Levitate or similar.

The story was consecutive in flow, book to book, and 150ish pages each and they were geared toward grade-school to middle-school kids.

Illustrations were included in the writing occasionally.

The writing and publishing was going on in the 1980's.

The locations and names were all fictitious.

The boys friends were not necessarily human as creatures were involved.

Comment: Is there anything else that you can remember? This is hardly anything to go on. Please [edit] anything else you can remember into your post.

Comment: So, were there 26 of these books?

Comment: I only knew of about 6 to 8 books. Not all letters of the alphabet were used as they only applied to the new spell. Thanks though. Your questions and input is greatly appreciated to help jog memories and little details!

Comment: Can you recall anything else? I tried looking for these names, and nothing really came up.

Comment: I have looked all over the internet for months on my own. The titles are close in accuracy. My grade school had these books in it's library. magic was at the heart of the book. The boy had 1 or two friends he either met or went with him.

Comment: These could be some obscure books, then! I don’t suppose that you know anyone who worked for your grade school library who might be able to recall these, or whether they might even still have the books? Even if they don’t, they may still have card records from that period.

Comment: Agreed. Doubtful but an option. The boys friends were not necessarily human. Creatures were involved.

Answer (score 4):

Myth Adventure series by Bob Asprin! Illustrated by Phil Foglio. 1978-2002.

Thank you all so much you've sent me looking in areas not thought of before and looking down other posts I found one among the 7000 plus entries. It sounded close and the name sounded familiar.  That led me to click on the answer given there. I wasn't sure till i looked up the illustrations! It is it!

Sorry, my details in memory were horrible! My titles were sooo incorrect! You are all awesome to help complete my journey to correct knowledge of this.

THANK YOU!

Comment: I just have to say that very little of the question matches up with the answer. :-D